# System.Windows.Input.TouchFrameEventHandler Does not work when Narrator is On

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, touchpad

I have used this `System.Windows.Input.TouchFrameEventHandler` event its working fine.

```
public static event TouchFrameEventHandler FrameReported;
```

But once the `Narrator` is **On** (present `Ctrl+ Windows+Enter` button to start the `Narrator`) the Event (`TouchFrameEventHandler`) does not work.

Any alternative solution for this will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: It seems it is a WPF based app? Not UWP app?

Comment: yes its WPF and using DesktopBridge